# BEST (singular noun; usually "the best") the most excellent thing or person

Tags: grammatical-number, superlative-degree

[[singular] (usually "the best") the most excellent thing or person](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/best_3): *We're the **best** of friends* (= very close friends).

Yet, I do not know how to interpret it as *a singular thing/person* here. Does *best* refer to a thing or to a person?

Quirk's page 1173 reads

> One or two verbs such as ''make'' and ''part'' can appear with a noun
> phrase complement, but not with an adjective phrase complement:
>
> *They parted the best of friends*. (In a sentence like *They parted
> friendly once more*, ''friendly once more'' would be not a complement
> but a verbless clause)

OED [**best**](https://oed.com/oed2/00020981)

Comment: It's contextual. _Look at all Jill's toy cars. The blue one is the best. // There are a lot of very talented footballers. And Messi is the best._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you need a plural subject for a similar example: _We, Barcelona F.C. players, are **the best of players**_, so does _best_ refer to a thing or to players?

Comment: Again, contextual. The blue cars are the best. // You can see the arguable conversion from adjectival usage. The blue cars / Barcelona players are the best [cars / players].  All superlatives can be used this way: The third edition is the latest / most recent/accurate.. The blue dress is the newest. Those clouds are the darkest I've ever seen.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _We're the best of friends_ is quite a trite everyday sentence, so what does **_best_** here refer to for native speakers? Either to a concept or to people

Comment: @GJC Not 100% sure what you are asking if the other comments didn't satisfy? "Best" is a concept, it doesn't only apply to any one specific category. It can be used to describe a person, place, or thing: "This is the best couch." (thing) / "She is the best mom." (person) / "That is the best store." (place). ...OR it can be used for something less concrete than a person, place, or thing: "It was the best feeling" (emotion), "This was the best day" (a period of time). In your example "best" applies to the word "friends".

Answer (score 1):

At face value, this form is not a set form: you find "the best of parents" ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22were%20the%20best%20of%20parents%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)), "the best of pets" ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20best%20of%20pets%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)), "the best of lands" ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20best%20of%20lands%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)), etc., and let's not forget, also "the best of friends".

- “A good book is the best of friends, the same today and for ever.” ([ref.](http://www.finedictionary.com/best%20friend.html))
  (*In this sentence "best" stands for "best friend" among all friends, not a person but tantamount to one, the book is more or less personalized.*)

You will notice that in all those constructions there is no question of reciprocity, in particular in the last case. Moreover, it is clear that either a person or several persons are involved or a thing (land) and  the definition of the noun "best" can be applied as signifying the most excellent parents, pets, land, friends, etc. We can conclude that all these constructions are of the type that answers to the principle of compositionality ([ref.](https://ling.yale.edu/whats-so-great-about-compositionality)), ie, the meaning of the construct is deducible from the meaning of its parts.
It is clear that in the use of the phrase that you consider the deducible meaning discussed above is not at all relevant:
1/ the referent of the complement of "of" above is the set of *all* parents, pets, etc. (Amongst all the parents, pets, etc. those named are/were/will be/etc. the best.),
2/ according to the meaning in question this is not true and the referent of "friends", is instead the same as that of the subject,
3/ there is an idea of reciprocity.
This makes already clear that compositionality does not operate here and it follows that the phrase must be an idiom. This is somewhat to be presumed from the addition made in the OALD (= very close friends).
It follows that there is no use seeking to give the different parts of this phrase a precise meaning; at least this seems to be now a strong conviction of mine. Not irrelevant to that contention might be the fact that in the SOED the forms "*best friend(s)*" and "*the best of*" are found in the section of the *special collocations, phrases and combinations*.

Comment: what PoS is **best** in _His last movie was best of all _ ? https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/all_3

Comment: So for OED it's an adjective, but for OALD it's a noun..., so unless _(the) best of friends_ is an idiom... https://oed.com/oed2/00020981

Comment: @GJC In analogy with "smallest of all", "fastest of all", "tallest of all", etc. where it can be considered that there is an ellipsis of a noun and an article ("was the smallest car of all"), I'd say that "best" is an adjective.

Comment: an adjective inside an idiom then in this case? Secondly, would the idiom include the defiinite article  _(**the**) best of friends_?

Comment: @GJC I think that you can't treat "the best of friends" and "best of all" on the same footing; there is no question of "best of all" being an idiom, it is not one.

Comment: I meant "the best of friends"

Comment: @GJC One characteristic of idioms is that they defy normal parsing, but I see no reason for not preserving  to "best" the nature of a noun, in keeping with the  classification of  "the best of friends" under the entry "best n.".

Answer (score -1):

I see this as a question of implied sets. *best* refers to a set of friends.

*friends* is a plural noun, a set of friends.

Usual and likely is that the friends in the set are all friends to each other. This allows us to interpret the sentence as *We are the best* {=best set of all possible sets} *of friends.*

Less usual and less likely is that they might all be friends of someone external as in “*we are all enemies to each other but are all friends of the king”*; this is both an unusual and unlikely circumstance. Nevertheless, the same analysis as in my previous paragraph may apply.

Comment: What meaning is used in _His last movie was **best** of all_ https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/all_3

Comment: @GJC ... the best of all = ... the best movie of the set of all movies that we might think of.

Comment: but what part of speech is it?

Comment: @GJC We are not asked that question.